# How can I prevent Jquery colorbox group from launching on click or mouseup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using Colorbox and have all of the standard functionality working. This question is outside of the normal colorbox usage scenario.

I need to be able to intercept the colorbox launch on click and evaluate a condition before allowing the colorbox to show.  So I have a group of images (using rel), and when any image is clicked I want to be able to run my own code to inspect some variables and decide if I can allow the colorbox popup to show.  If the condition is not set, I want to cancel the popup.  I haven't seen a simple way to do this interception/code injection in any of the samples online, although perhaps I have missed something.

Comment: Have you tried using the colorbox event hooks? http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ (see in the bottom)

Comment: I must admit I did not know how to cancel the colorbox open from inside the hook, and there was no documentation on how to do so, so I did not bother with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to stack your handlers and short-circuit the call to colorbox with an earlier handler. This should work, but I haven't tested:

Register a click handler first IN FRONT of the colorbox declaration, like so:

```
$('a.gallery')
  .on( 'click', onClickGallery )
  .colorbox({rel:'gal'});
```

And then stop immediate propagation if your condition isn't met:

```
onClickGallery = function ( event ) {
  var is_allowed = checkIsAllowed();
  if ( ! is_allowed ) { 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

I do this kind of thing in production all the time.  Good luck!

Comment: Tried this out, but found that although the colorbox did not launch (which is what we wanted), the page instead went and navigated to the href of the anchor.  So the event cancelled the colorbox call, but fell back on the default anchor behavior.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JasonLeverett even if your edit is approved, do not add comments into edits.

Comment: Sorry, it would not accept my edit unless I added more than a certain number of characters.  Since I only added 2 quote characters, I had to add unnecessary words in order for the form to allow me to submit it.

Comment: Hi Jason: I added event.preventDefault(); and return false; which should handle the situation.  In theory, simply "return false" should have done the trick, as it implies "event.preventDefault()" and "event.stopPropogation()".  Please give it a go now :)

Comment: Good job Michael.  Thanks for the insight and quick answer.